# Moving JSON Up in the hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, azure-sql-database

We have a table (MS SQL Azure) with a few columns which have the basic details like below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    id [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [firstname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lastname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [personInfo] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [createdOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [lastUpdateOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,     
)
```

The PersonInfo field has the JSON value of all the additional details about the person as shown below:

```json
{
   "personInfo":{
      "gender":"string",
      "address":{
         "streetAddress":"string",
         "city":"string",
         "district":"string",
         "stateProvince":"string",
         "postalCode":"string",
         "country":"string"
      },
      "emailAddress":"string",
      "addlEmails":[
         {
            "type":"string",
            "address":"string"
         }
      ],
      "businessPhone":"string",
      "mobilePhone":"string",
      "addlPhones":[
         {
            "type":"string",
            "number":"string",
            "prefix":"string",
            "suffix":"string"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I have a requirement to get the data out from the SQL as JSON with the person info attributes moved up in the level. Like below:

```json
{
   "id":"string",
   "firstname":"string",
   "lastname":"string",
   "id":"string",
   "gender":"string",
   "address":{
      "streetAddress":"string",
      "city":"string",
      "district":"string",
      "stateProvince":"string",
      "postalCode":"string",
      "country":"string"
   },
   "emailAddress":"string",
   "addlEmails":[
      {
         "type":"string",
         "address":"string"
      }
   ],
   "businessPhone":"string",
   "mobilePhone":"string",
   "addlPhones":[
      {
         "type":"string",
         "number":"string",
         "prefix":"string",
         "suffix":"string"
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there anyway i can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no JSON function that can "merge" columns and JSON or merge two JSONs, so there is no nice and efficient ways to do it. I would propose to try to change external interface to use nested format.

If this is not possible here are some not-so-nice workarounds.

This query parses some parts in personInfo JSON return then at the same level as standard columns and formats them together with for json:

```
select id, firstname, lastname, gender, address, emailAddress, addlEmails
from Person
cross apply openjson(personInfo,'$.personInfo')
            with (  gender nvarchar(10),
                    address nvarchar(max) as json,
                    emailAddress nvarchar(20),
                    addlEmails nvarchar(max) as json) info
for json path
```

This approach creates two JSON objects and concatenates them, and then replaces }{ with comma to merge them:

```
select 
    REPLACE((select id, firstname, lastname for json path, without_array_wrapper)  + json_query(personInfo,'$.personInfo'), '}{',',')
from Person
```